# VBSript to remove Start Menu for Autodesk

Tags: vbscript, scripting, shortcut, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I am able to remove desktop shortcut, but for some reason I cannot remove start menu shortcut. The name as it appears in Start Menu and ARP is Quick Uninstall Tool for Autodesk Inventor 2012. Others used it and it worked for them.
I used the following:

```
GenLogHandler "Deleting Start Menu shortcut for Uninstall tool"
RemSMshortcut="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\"
If objFSO.FileExists (RemSMshortcut & "\Uninstall Tool.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile (RemSMshortcut & "\Uninstall Tool.lnk")
```

**AND**

```
GenLogHandler "Deleting Start Menu shortcut for Uninstall tool"
autoDeskSM="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\"
If objFSO.FileExists (autoDeskSM & "\Uninstall Tool.lnk") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile (autoDeskSM & "\Uninstall Tool.lnk")
End If
```

Looks like for me its saving it under user profile C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Autodesk Pro\

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is it pinned? if so deleting wont remove it. you would need to execute the verb unpin as done in the following example script. [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-pin-items-to-Start-ee960ad8)